# Many2many to ir.ui.menu not showing all the menu items in odoo12

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I have created a many2many to 'ir.ui.menu' but it is only showing 80 menus while i have 600+ menu items. I need all the menu items to be seen.

This is how i defined my many2many:

```
menu_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.ui.menu',string="Menu")
```

#### XML

```
  <record id="menu_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">menu.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">hidden.menu</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Hide menu">
                <header>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" clickable="True" statusbar_visible="draft,done"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name" required="1"/>
                            <field name="user_ids" widget="many2many_tags" required="1"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="Hidden Menus" string="Hidden Menu's">
                            <field name="menu_ids">
                                <tree string="Hidden Menus" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="display_name" />
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Found the issue. it was because i used 'many2many_tags' widget. Don't know why all the records doesn't show on it though.

Comment: Is it not filtered on "tags" when using that specific widget? Also; good thing that you found it yourself. You can always answer your own question for future references.

Comment: IIRC the many2many_tags widget has some limitations because it was made for tags features. In usual contexts you shouldn't have more than 10 tags on something. Even here on SO the question tags are limited to 5 per question. Please add your XML view code to the question, because the answer or solution (changing the widget) depends on that code - just to add some quality to the question and answer.

Comment: I have added the xml code. I'm still having some problem. there are about 660 menu items. now i'm able to get 616 items through the many2many. Menu's with no child are not seen. For example menu employees is not visible. but employees/employess/contract is visible. You can recreate this just by adding a many2many to 'ir.ui.menu' @CZoellner

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get you. what did you mean by filtered on "tags"? @Ludo21South

Comment: By filtered I meant additional implicit restrictions (such as: company_id 1 AND tag == 'mytag'). Last time I worked with Odoo was quite a while ago so I don't recall exactly.

Comment: Depends on the user you're testing with. If you want to see every menu you should test with the superuser aka OdooBot aka `__system__`